# How to get specific part of url between two strings in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to extract a specific ID from the url I have.

https://myhost.com/ReferredSummary.aspx?PolicyId=4807307&EndorsementId=5941939&EditExisting=true&NewClient=true&Adjustment=True

the ID I need is = 4807307
It always have the strings PolicyId= before and &EndorsementId= after.

How Can I extract the the from the url.

Comment: So you want the PolicyId???

Comment: also duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: `const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myParam = urlParams.get('PolicyId');`

Answer (score 0):

Use split to split on `=` then split on `&` to get the value

```js
var a='https://myhost.com/ReferredSummary.aspx?PolicyId=4807307&EndorsementId=5941939&EditExisting=true&NewClient=true&Adjustment=True';
console.log(a.split('=')[1].split('&')[0])
```

Comment: Already answered in 100 duplicates

Answer (score 0):

A generic function like this should be able to get any parameter

```
function getUrlParameter(parameterName) {
  return new RegExp(parameterName + "=([^&]+)", "i").exec(document.URL)[1];
}
```

So a call like `getUrlParameter("policyid")` should do the trick.

This is current case insensitive, If you want the parameter to exactly match the paramter then instead use `return new RegExp(parameterName + "=([^&]+)").exec(document.URL)[1]`

Here is a snippet you can test:

```js
var testUrl = "https://myhost.com/ReferredSummary.aspx?PolicyId=4807307&EndorsementId=5941939&EditExisting=true&NewClient=true&Adjustment=True";

var selectElement = document.querySelector("#select"),
  resultElement = document.querySelector("#result");

// Adds parameters to select
testUrl.substring(testUrl.indexOf("?") + 1).split("&").forEach(function(param) {
  var newOption = document.createElement("option");
  newOption.textContent = newOption.value = param.substring(0, param.indexOf("="));
  selectElement.appendChild(newOption);
});

// Adds listener to select
selectElement.addEventListener("input", updateResult);
updateResult();

function updateResult() {
  resultElement.textContent = getUrlParameter(selectElement.selectedOptions[0].value);
}

function getUrlParameter(parameterName) {
  return new RegExp(parameterName + "=([^&]+)", "i").exec(testUrl)[1];
}
```

```html
<select id="select"></select>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: Already answered in 100 duplicates